# D3.js - Parallel coordinates - Change color of axis on brush

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to recreate [Parallel Coordinates](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) example.

Everytime an axis is brushed, I would like that particular axis to be highlighed by a change in color.

How do I do this?

Here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to implement:

[image]

I dont have a lot of experience with D3.js, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give that particular axis `g` a class and style that class, remove this class from all other axis-g's

Comment: For a single specific axis this is OK. But, for example,  if I had a total of 10 axes and I were to use a brush on any 5(or all) axes, I would want all those axes with brushes to be highlighted dynamically.

Comment: keep track of which axis have brushes and add the class to them or just add the class to the axis you get a brush callback, remove the class when you remove the brush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to highlight the brushed dimensions in a parallel chart:

https://bl.ocks.org/shashank2104/92bed39893773d085794be54b73c233e/56b1c0df3fa1579c6a6f60ef9f660e99901af935

**Code changes:**

1. Added dimension name as ID to the `<g>` element:

   ```
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "dimension").attr('data-id', function (d) { return d;})
   ```
2. In the **brushed** function, based on the computed **active dimensions**, a `selected` class can be added. (this can also be done in the brushend cb)

   ```
   // highlight brushed axes
   dimensions.forEach(function(dimension) {
      svg.select('g[data-id="'+dimension+'"]').classed('selected', actives.indexOf(dimension) > -1);
   });
   ```
3. Based on the class applied in the previous step, use CSS to highlight the brush path (feel free to change this as per your requirements):

   ```
   /* selected brushing dimension */
   g.dimension.selected .axis path.domain {
      stroke: red;
      stroke-width: 2px;
   }
   ```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Shashank. That was very helpful. I have added `g.dimension.selected text{fill: red; }` and `g.dimension.selected line{ stroke: red; }` to the css to also change the color of ticks and labels.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help!